# Output JSON Array onto Image Grid

Tags: javascript, php, json

> **Update** See the answer from Evil_skunk below, I was echoing two lines of code in `surfboards.php` to confirm a connection to the
>   database, but since that file was also where I was generating my JSON
>   output from the DB then those two lines made the output invalid (no longer only JSON) and I was unable to
>   print anything from that output. Working code is at the github link
>   below if anyone is interested.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I've researched and I can't find anything that helps here. I have some old assignment code from school that gathers data in a JSON array and outputs it into a `div` that creates an image grid. I'm trying to reuse it and I've gotten stuck.

I've already connected to my database and I'm printing JSON to a php file, I just can't get the syntax correct to have it print the array on the desired php page.

**What I have:**

- a page at [equipment.php](http://nalu.live/equipment.php) which has a `section` with an `id` of `board_table`
- a ton of array JSON data in [surfboards.php](http://nalu.live/surfboards.php)
- a JS block inside of `scripts/surfboard.js` that's trying to `.append` the JSON data to `board_table`
- I double checked and I am including `scripts/surfboard.js` in the included `head.php` file
- Nothing on page output
- Link to githuub project [nalu](https://github.com/SDillon001/nalu_html)

**What I'd like:**

- the JSON in `surfboards.php` to be dynamically output to `equipment.php` and append to `board_table` creating an image grid using the code block from `surfboard.js`

**Code from `surfboard.js`:**

```
//gets the JSON from our surfboards.php
$.getJSON("surfboards.php", function (data) {
      //loop through each surfboard in the JSON file and append id="board_table" with the surfboard information
      $.each(data.Surfboards, function (row) {
          $("#board_table").append(
            '<div class="surfboard"><a href="equipment.php?id=' + data.Surfboard[row].Surfboard.id + '"><img src="images/' + data.Surfboard[row].Surfboard.imageName + '" alt="' + data.Surfboard[row].Surfboard.imageName + '"><p>' + data.Surfboard[row].Surfboard.name + '</p><p>$' + data.Surfboard[row].Surfboard.price + '</p></a></div>');
      });
});
```

**Code from `equpiment.php`:**

```
<div class="flexbox_container">
    <section id="board_table">
      <h1><--Boards Should Show Here --></h1>
      <!--/* Javascript will publish our products here */-->
    </section>
</div>
```

**Sample JSON block from `surfboards.php`:**

```
{
"Surfboards": [
{
    "Surfboard":
    {
        "id": "1",
        "sNumber": "6",
        "boardName": "Pat Curren Balsa Gun 12'",
        "imageName": "camera.png",
        "year": "1950",
        "weight": "32",
        "dimensions": "21",
        "caDescription": "This board was built in Hawaii by Pat Curren, for Bev Morgan (early California wetsuit inventor and diving pioneer)",
        "infoCard": "placeholder_infoCard",
        "notes": ""
    }
},
```

**Code from `head.php` file:**

```
  <!-- Start Scripts -->
  <script src="jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/surfboard.js"></script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test it locally I mocked your surfboards.php and just printed out your provided json (because I don't have your database)

For me it look's like your json structure does not correspond to your output in `surfboard.js`

```
$.each(data.Surfboards, function (row) {
      $("#board_table").append(
        '<div class="surfboard"><a href="equipment.php?id=' + data.Surfboard[row].Surfboard.id + '">...</a></div>'
      );
});
```

`data.Surfboard` is not available - because you json starts with Surfboard**s**. 
To make it easier I would use

```
 $.each(data.Surfboards, function (row, element) {
     $("#board_table").append(
         '<div class="surfboard"><a href="equipment.php?id=' + element.Surfboard.id + '"><img src="images/' + element.Surfboard.imageName + '" alt="' + element.Surfboard.imageName + '"><p>' + element.Surfboard.name + '</p><p>$' + element.Surfboard.price + '</p></a></div>'
      );
 });
```

With that code I get the item displayed in the #board_table

And a second thing - in your github repo you still use $("#board_table").append**To** - but I think you already found that issue on your own :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @Evil_skunk. However, I added your code above but still no page output. I've updated the repo and the live site. 

It's strange, it seems like it's not finding the `#board_table` div?

And yes, `.appendTo` was an old incorrect attempt to fix it that I forgot to overwrite with another commit :)

Comment: strange - i've tried it again with your current code and it worked for me - i just replaced the content of `surfboards.php` with the static json from `surfboards_php_output.json` (deleted first two and last 4 rows) and the browser is showing me > 100 surfboard items (divs) - styling needs improvement but it looks like its basically working :-) - btw. thanks for source code credits

Comment: do you get any error messages in browsers debugger console? - if not maybe check debugger network tab and check what the request to `surfboards.php` returns

Comment: Ahh, ok, I did what you said @Evil_skunk and it works...added the static JSON to `surfboards.php' and it's showing on the `equipment.php` page. The only issue now is that the database info is going to change...e.g. I need to replace all of the images with actual boards not placeholders. I have an excel sheet with corresponding filenames that I'll upload and overwrite the current database. The `surfboards_original.php` is now that file that's outputting the info from the DB to a webpage. Is there a way to pull from that and display it on `equipment.php` so it will update as the DB updates?

Comment: and no worries for the credit! I'm a big believer in attribution! :)

Comment: oh, and I have CSS from the other project that will place them all in a grid and make it look nice ;)

Comment: ahh thanks for providing an url - now i saw the error - your are echoing out 2 lines in `connection.php` (line 16/18) - so a call to `surfboards_original.php` will always contain this two lines in the beginning and therefore it's not a valid JSON anymore. Remove this two output lines and you are able to use the file again as source for your `getJSON` method - the rest of the file is valid json with data directly from your database.

Comment: Hahaha!! I didn't even think of that....echo removed, it's working. I was trying to make sure I had connected to the DB. Thank you SO much for working this out, I'm pretty new to using JSON (and coding in general). Much appreciated! @Evil_skunk